# Need info on malloc trace

Tags: c, memory, gcc, malloc

When I try the below code I am not clearly able to analyze malloc api internal calls.What I am not clear is about the system call mmap is called only once for 2 or more malloc calls.If I am assigning more then 4069 bytes also it is calling only one mmap internally(trace is identified by using strace -p processid ).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
int *p,*q;
sleep(20);
p=malloc(5096);
printf("p=%p\n",p);
q=malloc(4096);
printf("q=%p\n",q);
sleep(2);
return 0;
}
```

strace OUTPUT:

```
root@TEST:/home/harish# strace  -p 6109
Process 6109 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>
) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xeca000
brk(0xeec000)                           = 0xeec000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 14), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f10b7bc7000
write(1, "p=0xeca010\n", 11)            = 11
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({20, 0},
0x7ffc34a51790)      = 0
write(1, "q=0xecb020\n", 11)            = 11
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({2, 0}, 0x7ffc34a51790)       = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

What I am looking is ,if malloc is used more then once will it call more then one mmap since memory is exceeding in two malloc's beyond 4096

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to understand `malloc` internals, look into the source code. On Linux systems it is likely to be in [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) but there are other implementations of the C standard library (the [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) source code is nice to read) and of `malloc` (e.g. [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)). [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/319070/40065) is a very fast and simple `malloc`, but completely useless since always failing.

Grossly speaking, `malloc` is always built above [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) primitives (i.e. [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), for Linux listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) modifying the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Concretely that means mostly [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & `munmap(2)` (and perhaps also the obsolete [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html), etc...) on Linux.

The OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) is managing the virtual address space by [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) (often 4Kbytes on x86) using the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). Hence the page size is defined by the hardware.

The implementation of `malloc` & `free` can be tricky. First, it obviously won't `mmap` an entire page of 4Kbytes for every small `malloc` (of e.g. 24 or 32 bytes), since that would waste space. So it would call `mmap` once in a while, and organize the obtained pages wisely. Then, it probably would `mmap` a large segment (of many consecutive pages) for large allocations (e.g. some `malloc` of two megabytes). It also tries to reuse previously `free`-d memory zones, because calling `mmap` is much slower than an ordinary function call.

So most `malloc`-s handles at least differently small zones and larges ones, and some `malloc`-s are even more clever. The lib would for example manage a linked list of small zones of same size, and to get the initial space for that it might `mmap` one or several consecutive pages. Then, `free`-ing such small zones is adding the `free`-d zone to that linked list. So most *small* `malloc`-s won't use `mmap` but simply get an element for such lists. For large zones the implementation might `mmap` and `munmap` each of them. Some implementations of `malloc` are keeping the size of the zone in some word just before the zone.

In the details, the implementation is doing considerably more tricky things (i.e. don't use lists, but [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), use several [regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management) or arenas, could allocate tiny mallocs of two words in specific address ranges, etc...). You can find many research papers on `malloc` (because there are many trade-offs to consider), and several tutorials, e.g. [this](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/understanding-glibc-malloc/). Read also about [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) & [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (sometimes using the [Boehm conservative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) is worthwhile in C programs: you would use `GC_MALLOC` instead of `malloc` and you won't care about calling `free`), e.g. read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/).

GNU libc provides [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html), [malloc_info(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html), [mallopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html), [mcheck(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mcheck.3.html) etc. The [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) program is very useful to hunt memory leaks and corruptions.

BTW, you might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (and perhaps also [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) ...) directly:

```
strace ./yourprog
```

<sup>PS. My answer is focused on Linux. On other OSes the details are different.</sup>